# Trying to write a bash script that can be toggled with scroll lock and replace key presses

Tags: bash, autohotkey

Basically I'm trying to reproduce [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/25093-mac-style-dvorak-qwerty-command-layout-switcher-for-windows/) autohotkey script that I use in windows for linux. I makes a qwerty keyboard act like a dvorak one unless Alt, Control or a windows key is pressed, I would also like to be able to enable or disable this based on if scroll lock is enabled or disabled. Can this be done and how?

Comment: which window/desktop manager? gnome? you would simply bind the scroll lock key to a script that toggles keyboard layout. you'd probably also have to bind scroll lock to a non-modifier key using xmodmap

Comment: Using gnome. Would that also let me use normal qwerty shortcuts like control-v to paste? Thats the whole point of the script is that when control and alt are pressed it reverts to qwerty until they are released.

Comment: I'm not familiar with dvorak. To switch between layouts, you could have two layout files, ".xmodmap_dvorak" and ".xmodmap_qwerty" (create the using "xmodmap -pke", for example), then all the toggle script needs to do is call "xmodmap layout_file". But the .xmodmap layout only allows you to modify the bindings for modifiers like shift and alt-gr, not for control, alt, super. For these, you'd probably have to rely on your desktop manager's shortcuts.

Comment: You can also try ``xbindkeys``

Comment: if you only have a small list of shortcuts that you want to make work independently of your current layout, you could bind (with xbindkeys for example) those shortcuts to an xdotool call, for example ctr+k => "xdotool key ctrl+v", and activate these when dvorak activates. Also, if you're willing to use a window manager like stumpwm, I could answer your question thoroughly.

Comment: thought xdotool would work well but seem to be having trouble does [this](https://imgur.com/OcYctWJ) look right I can't figure out why it isn't working I have xdotool working if I manually type it into the terminal so install is fine

Comment: I don't remember much about gnome, but have you tried removing the quotes? How about a "touch /tmp/script_ran" && xdotool ctrl+f" and check whether /tmp/script_ran exists?

Comment: If I remove the quotes it will just type U when I try and use the shortcut. running with touch as well as completely replacing the command with the touch seems to indicate it isn't running but I can't figure out why if I replace it with xterm it runs

Comment: Try AutoKey, the point of it is to have an autohotkey-like experience in Linux

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
caps="$(xset -q | grep Caps | sed -E "s/ //g;s/[0-9]*//g" | cut -d ":" -f 3)"
lang="us"
setxkbmap us
while true; do
  newCaps="$(xset -q | grep Caps | sed -E "s/ //g;s/[0-9]*//g" | cut -d ":" -f 3)"
  if [ "$caps" != "$newCaps" ]; then
    caps="$newCaps"
    if [ "$lang" == "us" ]; then
      setxkbmap dvorak
      lang="dvorak"
    else
      setxkbmap us
      lang="us"
    fi
  fi
done
```

It seems that this `xset` captures new state of `Caps Lock` only when some other key is pressed after pressing `Caps Lock`.